# Emacs, ESS and Rmarkdown: Is this the way compile is supposed to work?

Tags: emacs, r-markdown, ess

I'm trying to get Emacs, ESS and Rmarkdown to work together for the first time. Therefore, the problem might be me, and not the software.

I have this program as Prob_11.Rmd:

````
---
title: "Problem 11, Page 414"
author: "Kevin"
date: "13 Apr 2023"
output: html_document
---

### Load the sample data ###

Loading the sample data table into two vectors:

``` {r}

(age11 <- c(18, 10, 3, 15, 12, 14, 15, 4, 20, 8))

(age16 <- c(6, 7, 14, 5, 14, 12, 3, 9, 4, 7))

```
````

I get this as output after choosing Markdown->Preview & Export->Compile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<title>*markdown-output*</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>

</head>

<body>

<h3 id="load-the-sample-data">Load the sample data</h3>
<p>Loading the sample data table into two vectors:</p>
<pre class="{r}"><code>
(age11 &lt;- c(18, 10, 3, 15, 12, 14, 15, 4, 20, 8))

(age16 &lt;- c(6, 7, 14, 5, 14, 12, 3, 9, 4, 7))
</code></pre>

</body>
</html>
```

This looks correct, except that I was expecting the last two lines to look like:

```
> (age11 <- c(18, 10, 3, 15, 12, 14, 15, 4, 20, 8))
 [1] 18 10  3 15 12 14 15  4 20  8
> (age16 <- c(6, 7, 14, 5, 14, 12, 3, 9, 4, 7))
 [1]  6  7 14  5 14 12  3  9  4  7
```

Am I doing something wrong? Am I misunderstanding what RMarkdown is doing? I tried options like 'echo=TRUE' and 'eval=TRUE' without success.

Comment: I think you are hitting Emacs's 'markdown' (no R) processor. I generally deal with my (frequent) RMarkdown files using a little wrapper [`render.r`](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/blob/master/inst/examples/render.r) I wrote years ago.  And I find using it via 'compile-command' quite handy: `C-c C-c` (or `M-x compile-command`) after which I once replace the `make ...` invocation.  The next times Emacs remembers, so it is just `C-c C-c`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dirk Eddelbuettel's suggestion of his render.r executable, I was able to boil it down to the commands I need to render the Rmarkdown.

I run this *once* in the R console window of Emacs running ESS:

```
   library(rmarkdown)
```

Then, everytime I want to update the document I'm working on, I run:

```
   render("working_file.Rmd")
```

For me, that outputs an HTML document, that I view in my browser.

I feel certain that there's a better, easier way to do this, in the Emacs/ESS/poly-R/Rmarkdown system, but this is what I needed to get me unstuck, and until I have some time to spare, this is as far as I'm taking it.